# Deep shopping model missing file

Tags: python-3.x, deep-learning, tensorflow, resnet

I tried to reproduce results of the following [Deep-shopping model](https://github.com/wenxinxu/deep-shopping), but I don't know where to find the file `simple_resnet.py`, or how to start to write my own version. Can you give me any hint?